# Check if value (string) exist in Mongo DB query in PHP 7

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, php-7

I need to check if string exist in MongoDB query in PHP7. In old days it was easy like so:

```
// Trying to find $username

$dbserver = new MongoClient();
$db = $dbserver->databasename;
$collection = $db->collectionname;
$queryDbFind = $collection->findOne(array("user" => $username));
if(empty($queryDbFind[$username])){
    echo "empty";
} else {
    echo "not empty";
};
```

Now there is new PHP driver, where i perform query as follows:

```
$db = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017")
$query1 = new MongoDB\Driver\Query(['user' => $username], ['limit' => 1, 'projection' => ['user' => 1, '_id' => 0]]);
$dbread1 = $db->executeQuery('goodcv.userbase', $query1);
```

This is where I am stuck. I get the object, but can not check if $username exist in that object.

I have tried:

```
$result1 = $dbread1->toArray();
if(empty($result1->user)){
        echo "user exist";
    } else {
        echo "user does not exist";
    };
```

Does not work :(
Only way to return result is:

```
foreach($result1 as $row){
    echo $row->user;
};
```

But this is not proper way to do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library) mongo library with [this](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) PECL, then you should use the methods of the Collection object, like you did before ($collection->findOne(...)). What driver are you using???

Comment: Hello Eric, Thanks for responding!
I user this driver: [link](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb)
It does not support findOne() command anymore (as I understand). You run query command (new MongoDB\Driver\Query) and in filter you can specify what you look for and in options you specify how many documents you want to return, what fields, etc..

Comment: I understand that legacy driver does not work with PHP 7 anymore.

Comment: You need to use the driver I linked. It's the offcial driver from Mongo for PHP and it does support PHP 7 (see PECL link). Then you can use findOne. Edit: it's the same link? I don't know what you are doing then.

Comment: I got it now. I should have read more carefully. I have the driver but not the library you gave in 1st link. I am using XAMPP and have no composer (no admin rights). Can you please tell how to install library manually? I downloaded the package, should i copy "src" folder somewhere under XAMPP/PHP? Thank you again!

Comment: Copy the src folder in your project root and link the library from your PHP file. I do not remember what are the exact files you need to include though.

Comment: Works now as should be. Thank you for the help!